# How do I make my Button size match parent RelativeLayout size exactly in android?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I thought that match_parent would do the trick however when I set match_parent to the width it stretches the whole RelativeLayout. However the height is correct...

Here is my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/moreRelativeLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.24"
            android:layout_gravity="center">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/moreButton"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:background="@drawable/more_menu_icon"
                android:alpha="0.5"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.24"
                android:onClick="moreIconPressed"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:alpha="0.5"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:text="More"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/moreButton"
                android:layout_marginTop="-3dp"
                android:textSize="12dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/moreBiggerButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#000000" />

        </RelativeLayout>
```

It is the last Button(moreBiggerButton) that I wish to cover the whole RelativeLayout (moreRelativeLayout). What am I doing wrong? I thought something like this would be as simple as setting both width and height to match_parent :S Please help.

Comment: There is nothing wrong. `moreBiggerButton` does cover everything.

Comment: It is stretching the moreRelativeLayout though. Something has to be wrong :S I do not wish for it to alter moreRelativeLayout at all. Just to take its shape.

Comment: I dont understand: you said you wish it to cover the whole RelativeLayout. And it does cover as you wish...

Comment: Ok. My bad. Maybe I should reword this... how do I prevent it from stretching the original RelativeLayout? Only when I add this button does the RelativeLayout stretch its width which I do not want.

Comment: Change `match_parent` to `wrap_content` then.

Comment: That did it! Thank you!